# Management of verificationStatus, accountLinkingStatus, UserStorage, and user's ID in Google Conversational Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I am very confused on how I have to handle the `verificationStatus` and `accountLinkingStatus` attributes of requests in a Google Conversational Action app that I am working with, specially now that user ID is deprecated.

I need to identify a user, so I need to store data in the **UserStorage**, only if the user is Verified and gave consent, but since I also have AccountLinking with OAuth, I don't know if it is possible that a user with AccountLinking and not verified could exist, or how to manage or face the user's ID management.

As much as I read the documentation, I cannot understand how the conditions can occur with each other, and if there is mutual exclusion in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user cannot have a valid account while also being unverified. If the Google Assistant device cannot verify who the user is, it will not send account linking credentials.

However, a user can be verified with voice matching in a way that doesn't require you to have an account.

It's also possible for neither to be true, particularly when a guest is interacting with an action.

Below is a table to show the set of possible states.

|  | Not Verified | Verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Not Linked** | ✓ | ✓ |
| **Linked** | ✕ | ✓ |

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. So useful, thank you

Comment: How can an accessToken be invalid? I mean, I can think only in one scenario: Google sends my Action a valid token (because I suposse Google gets a new one if current has expired) and it expires just after the response. It is correct? I mean, I will try to get user data from my company oAuth server but I don't know if I should control these cases